# Continuity and Connectedness

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

It is well known that if $f:M\to N$ is a continuous function and $(M,d)$ and $(N,d')$ are metric spaces, given $A$, a connected subset in $M$, $f(A)$ is a connected subset of $N$. I am looking for some sort of converse for this theorem; I first thought of "If $(M,d)$ and $(N,d')$ are metric spaces and $f:M\to N$ is a function such that for every connected subset $A$ of $M$, $f(A)$ is connected, then $f$ is continuous". However,
$$f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
\sin \left(\frac{1}{x}\right), & \text{if $x\neq 0$}\\
0, & \text{if $x=0$}\\
\end{cases}$$
is a counterexample. Are there any additional conditions to the hypothesis that make a similar theorem true?

Answer (score 1):

Functions that map connected sets to connected sets are called [Darboux-continous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis)). For functions on the real numbers, Darboux-continuity coincides with ordinary continuity for functions with only simple discontinuities.